# How to change PS4 controller light bar color in GLFW (preferrably Java LWJGL method)

Tags: lwjgl, glfw

So I've been searching through the internet and cannot seem to find an answer to this. How would I make the dualshock 4 controller light bar change color and change brightness?

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings and select devices, then select controllers. This is where you can adjust the brightness of the light bar. However changing the colour is a bit more complex. There are a few you tube videos on “changing light bar colour on ps4 controller”

Comment: Definitely not an answer. I asked how to do it with GLFW (which is a c library for OpenGL) using the LWJGL wrapper preferably, which is in Java. Your answer met none of these requirements, instead you answered how to do it in Windows, not in code. Be a little more careful reading these questions next time please.